# Adding custom classes to react-virtualized grid

Tags: css, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm trying to add some custom classes to a grid component in react, I want to add a class if the row is even, a class is the row is odd and also a class to the first first grid row

I've got both arguments working, if I comment one out the other works but I can't wrap my head around how to get these two arguments to both work together, I don't want to use and && or || if that makes sense ... or if there's a more elegant way of writing my code

```
    getRowClassName(row) {
    return row % 2 === 0 ? "evenRow" : "oddRow";
    return row === 0 ? "FirstRow" : "";
}
```

I tried this but this only runs the second argument

```
    getRowClassName(row) {
    return row % 2 === 0 ? "evenRow" : "oddRow", row === 0 ? "FirstRow" : "";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you return an object which contains both elements: `return {even: /*...*/, first: /*...*/}`

Comment: I think that's what I've been trying to figure out how to do, but I can't get that to work as expected at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution to my problem is to just separate these two arguments in to two different functions as such

```
getFirstRowClassName(row) {
    return row === 0 ? "FirstRow" : "";
}

getRowClassName(row) {
    return row % 2 === 0 ? "evenRow" : "oddRow";
}
```

And then I just add these both to my grid